# HDS music stream in Sonos/VLC?

Tags: stream, video-streaming, sonos

Searched everywhere and tried different things, but none of this seems to work. Is there a way to play this HD radio stream - http://prepublish.f.qaotic.net/a01/ngrp:cienradioshd-10002_all/playlist_b346000.abst - in VLC, or consequently, in Sonos player?

The website of the radio is http://la100.cienradios.com/hd/

It seems to be HDS fragmented stream. I've tried adding playlist.m3u8 at the end etc, but it does not connect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Referer`, so I don't think it's possible to play it on VLC.

```
Link: http://prepublish.f.qaotic.net/a01/ngrp:cienradioshd-10002_all/master.m3u8
Referer: Use the browser Network tools to see it
```